# why do i get a blank screen after uploading modules to sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

After uploading modules via the admin panel, I end up at a blank screen with zip file in the uploads dir but not uncompressed or installed.

i dont see anthing in any of the log files.

ideas what could be wrong?

thx

Comment: Sounds like a server configuration issue - hitting some kind of fatal error.  Did you check the PHP error log?  Fatal errors don't get logged in SugarCRM's log.

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me at this line
  require_once($target_manifest) on 
file ModuleInstall/PackageManager/PackageManager.php

The problem which I'm trying to solve is that the require_once does not work with $tager_manifest which use upload://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

As a workarround I modified it to the path to the manifestfile